# Silverlight Transparency

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, transparency

**Question:**

Can a constituent UserControl be transparent in parts for it's external container?

**Details:**

I have a dialog that I'd like to pull into a separate UserControl. The control contains a Border with a background that has an alpha transparency with a Grid inside it that has a white background and all the content. In xaml markup, it looks something like:

```
    <Border Margin="22,28,20,18" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="#30D7D7D7">
        <Grid Margin="155,148,145,198" Background="#FFFEFEFE">
            <TextBlock Margin="17,19,32,20" Text="Dialog part goes here." TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

**Problem:**

When I move that to a user control, even if I set the user control's background to Transparent, it doesn't display a transparent background for the Border; it's solid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UserControl itself will have a background color.  Make sure the UserControl you've moved your code to has `Background=Transparent`.

Comment: You were absolutely right here, I should have marked this correct a long time ago.